# Split one column into multiple columns with formatted output

Tags: text-formatting

I want to print the output of usernames from /etc/passwd into multiple columns. 
The output from my server is

[root@master vdabas]# cat -n /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d":"

```
 1  root
 2  bin
 3  daemon
 4  adm
 5  lp
 6  sync
 7  shutdown
 8  halt
 9  mail
10  operator
11  games
12  ftp
13  nobody
14  systemd-network
15  dbus
16  polkitd
17  sshd
18  postfix
19  vdabas
20  vani
21  delhi
```

I want the output to be as below:

```
 1  root            8  halt             15  dbus
 2  bin             9  mail             16  polkitd
 3  daemon          10 operator         17  sshd
 4  adm             11 games            18  postfix
 5  lp              12 ftp              19  vdabas
 6  sync            13 nobody           20  vani
 7  shutdown        14 systemd-network  21  delhi
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `pr` command to format in 3 columns (`-3`), omitting pagination (`-T`):

```
cat -n /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d":" | pr -T -3
```

or perhaps

```
awk -F: '{print NR,$1}' /etc/passwd | pr -T -3
```

Answer (score 0):

Under macOS (and maybe other BSD flavors) use

```
 pr -t -3
```

(lower case "t")

In your peculiar case, if your input were in a file list.txt

```
pr -3 -l7 list.txt
```

would do the job. As said, for my BSDish macOS "pr" command.
(note that the option -l automatically supresses the headers if the sum of the -l argument is not greater than the sum of both, the header and trailer depths)